# How can i animate these planes?

Tags: animation, physics, unreal-engine

I need help with animating these planes. I want to make the planes move with the cylinder but they are nearly impossible to weight paint them and not every Blender physic system is easy to get into UE4. So how is the best way to animate them?

I added an example to illustrate the problem:
[image]

You have to imagin the thing on the picture is a bird wing and these little things are simple planes with a feather texture on it. I attached them with the particle system but i dont know how to convert a hair dynamic simulation to a keyframe animation or how i can animate this wing at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You image is not very clear and it doesn't help understanding what you are really trying to achieve. Could you clarify?

Comment: So its very hard to explain but i can try it on a different way. I want to make polygon feathers for a game. At the moment i am using simple textured planes which are attached by the particle system. But i dont know how to get a blender hair dynamic simulation to a keyframe animation for ue4. Also, with so many small objects, it's hard to animate them by hand. I've been looking for an alternative or solution for a long time now.